# Monodromy Properties of Heun Functions in the Singularity Parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I'm studying a physical problem involving Heun equation and the local Heun functions.
Heun equation is the Fuchsian differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac {d^2w}{dz^2} + 
\left[\frac{\gamma}{z}+ \frac{\delta}{z-1} + \frac{\epsilon}{z-a} \right] 
\frac {dw}{dz} 
+ \frac {\alpha \beta z -q} {z(z-1)(z-a)} w = 0
\end{equation}
with the constraint
\begin{equation}
\epsilon=\alpha+\beta-\gamma-\delta+1
\end{equation}
The solution which is holomorphic and equals $1$ at the singular point $z = 0$ is called the *local Heun function* denoted as $H\ell(a, q, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, z)$. I am interested in the properties of this function as a function of the "singularity parameter" $a$, in particular branch points and monodromies. Is there any paper or reference I should read?

Comment: Have you found something? I deal with the similar problem

Comment: Not really no, please let's keep in touch if we find something!

Comment: Same issue here